# ServiceStack RequiredPermission is not validating my user

Tags: c#, authorization, servicestack

I cant seem to get our tests to pass the `RequiredPermission` attribute on our ServiceStack service. Can someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong here?

***The assumption is that `RequiredPermission` uses the `session.Permissions` list.***

Our `UserViewModel` is setup as follows

```
public class UserViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public UserViewModel()
    {
        Groups = new List<GroupModel>();
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; } // This should never be populated on the way out.

    public IList<GroupModel> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

The GroupModel is similar with a list of `SecuritySettings` within it. Every call to the Service Layer returns a fully hydrated UserViewModel containing a list of Groups and each group contains a list of SecuritySettings.

When a user Authenticates, we run this

```
    public override void OnAuthenticated ( IServiceBase authService,
                                          IAuthSession session,
                                          IOAuthTokens tokens,
                                          Dictionary<string, string> authInfo )
    {
        session.Id = _userViewModel.Id.ToString();
        session.UserName = _userViewModel.Email;
        session.FirstName = _userViewModel.FirstName;
        session.DisplayName = string.Format( "{0} {1}", _userViewModel.FirstName, _userViewModel.LastName );

        session.Roles = new List<string>();
        session.Permissions = new List<string>();

        if ( _userViewModel.Groups != null )
        {
            foreach ( var group in _userViewModel.Groups )
            {
                // Add user Groups to "Roles"
                session.Roles.Add( group.Name );

                if ( @group.SecuritySettings == null ) continue;
                foreach ( var securitySetting in @group.SecuritySettings )
                {
                    // Add group SecuritySettings to "Permissions"
                    session.Permissions.Add( securitySetting.Name );
                }
            }
        }

        var mapper = new AutoMapper<UserModel>();
        _container.Register( mapper.BuildFrom( _userViewModel ) );

        //Important: You need to save the session!
        authService.SaveSession( session, SessionExpiry );
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that my tests are still returning "Unauthorized" on my UserServiceInterface method

```
    [RequiredPermission("Read User")]
    public object Get( UserRequest request )
    {
        return new UserResponse { User = _userService.GetById( request.Id ) };
    }
```

I can confirm that the `UserViewModel.Groups[0].SecuritySettings[0].Name == "Read User"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution to this issue is to call the `base.OnAuthenticated` method at the end of the CustomCredentialsAuthProvider.OnAuthenticated method.

```
    public override void OnAuthenticated ( IServiceBase authService,
                                           IAuthSession session,
                                           IOAuthTokens tokens,
                                           Dictionary<string, string> authInfo )
    {

        // truncated for brevity

        //Important: You need to save the session!s
        authService.SaveSession( session, SessionExpiry );

        // THIS ENSURES THE SESSION IS ACCESSABLE BY THE APP 
        base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation of the [RequiredPermissionAttribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/RequiredPermissionAttribute.cs#L45):

```
public bool HasAllPermissions(IAuthSession session)
{
    return this.RequiredPermissions
        .All(requiredPermission => session != null 
            && session.HasPermission(requiredPermission));
}
```

The default implementation of which just checks [AuthUserSession.HasPermission()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/AuthUserSession.cs#L58), i.e:

```
public virtual bool HasPermission(string permission)
{
    return this.Permissions != null && this.Permissions.Contains(permission);
}
```

Which is overridable if you're using a CustomAuthSession. I'd recommend overriding `HasPermission()` and putting a breakpoint so you can introspect your session instance - as the current behavior only fails when the session doesn't have the required permission.

Comment: I just found the problem. Adding `base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);` to my `OnAuthenticated` method passed the session data to wherever it needed to go.

Comment: Thanks for your help and for making such a great product.

Comment: @mythz Any idea why, when using the *GoogleOAuth2Provider*, this breakpoint is never hit, and the attribute is basically ignored (all requests allowed)? It's fine for *CredentialsAuthProvider*. Thanks

Comment: @JMK I've added an integration test to check for this in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/63cf032d8f086a2c4f62cc13215efdaba167dd4b) and can verify the breakpoint in CustomUserSession `override bool HasPermission(permission,authRepo){}` is getting hit. So I'd upgrade to the latest version first, if it's still an issue can you upload a stand-alone repro that I can run locally to Github so I can identify the issue.

Comment: @mythz Thanks very much, willdo!